# Make ASP.NET Web Forms button look like a Windows Forms button

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, button

I've just been dabbling with creating a web form in Visual Studio 2012.

The default appearance of a button when I drag it onto my form from the Tools pallet and run the form is just flat.  Running the form, it doesn't change appearance based on being enabled or disabled.  "Pushing" it shows no change in appearance.  In other words, it isn't nearly as nice as a Windows Forms button created in the same way.

Do I have to write some CSS code or something to change this?

(My default browser for debug is Firefox.)

Comment: Yes, you will have to add some CSS to style the button the way you want it.

Comment: http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ - that was hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to customize a button. [jsfiddle.net/8cqcF](http://jsfiddle.net/8cqcF/)

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .submit {
        border: 1px solid #563d7c;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px;
        background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=6);
        background-position-y: 465px;
        background-position-x: 5px;
        background-color: #563d7c;
    }
</style>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Submit" CssClass="submit"/>
```

Thesedays, a lot of people use front-end frameworks such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) is the example of bootstrap buttons.

[image]